# this.store.find is not a function

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-data

i would like to get all my events from the API ROUTE /events (GET) in my IndexRoute, so i'm trying like this:

```
SiteApp.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 model: function() {
  return this.store.find('events');
 }
});
```

And is returning the error:

```
this.store.find is not a function
```

I'm not understand why this.

I'm loading the libs in this sequence:

```
jQuery
Ember Data
Ember Template Compiler
Ember Debug
```

Thanks.

Comment: are you using ember-cli? which versions of ember and ember-data are you using?

Comment: I'm not using Ember-cli. I'm using Node.js, Express.js Mongo and Ember. Unfortunately, i don't know how to use Ember-cli with Node and Express :/ The versions are: Ember 2.0.2 Ember-data 2.0.1

Comment: I would think that ember-data should be loaded after the ember js file.

Comment: Really?? Let my try!!

Comment: the docs for globals mode are kind of hard to track down so not too familiar. Just for your future selfs sake I would try to learn ember-cli

Comment: find should be findRecord and findAll in Ember 1.13 onwards.

Comment: still doesn't work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your order of loading libraries:

```
jQuery
Ember Debug // depends on jQuery
Ember Template Compiler // depends on Ember Debug
Ember Data // depends on Ember Debug
```

Answer (score 0):

`return this.store.find('events');` should possibly be singular if your model is.

`return this.store.find('event');`